# What are mixed effects without random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-estimating-equations

Please pardon my ignorance, what is a mixed effects model without random effects, without any random intercept or random slope? Is this similar to marginal GEE model?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as a mixed effect without random effects. Suppose I have an equation of random variables such as

$$Y = g(X; \theta)$$

where $g: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. To turn whatever this model is into a mixed effect model I simply make a substitution

$$\theta := \underbrace{\gamma}_{\text{Fixed Effect}} + \sum_{i=1}^k \underbrace{\gamma_i}_{\text{Random Effect}} \mathbb{I}[i=\text{Group}]$$

for some collection of groupings $\text{Group} \in \{1, \ldots, k \}$. If you drop the random effects then you are just left with

$$\theta := \underbrace{\gamma}_{\text{Fixed Effect}}$$

which is not different than what you started with.

---

However, it is meaningful to have random effects without fixed effects:

$$\theta := \sum_{i=1}^k \underbrace{\gamma_i}_{\text{Random Effect}} \mathbb{I}[i=\text{Group}]$$

---

[GEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation) on the other hand is a parameter estimation technique that doesn't have an explicit connection to mixed effects.

Comment: Thanks Galen, that makes sense. I agree there are differences between GEE and mixed effects models, However if the random effects component is dropped , does the fixed effects parameter estimates from mixed effects model have the `same interpretation` as parameter estimates from GEE ?.

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai These are logically independent considerations. I could estimate such as fixed effect in many different ways, including using GEE as an objective.