# Suitability of multilevel poisson regression model

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am planning to fit a statistical model to a dataset in which there are details about bird-farms from various geographic locations, 7 environmental variables, egg_hatching years, and eggs_hatched. An image of data is given here. This is just an example, and like this, I have data for 20 farms; each farm has data from 1972 - 2021. May I know what kind of modeling would be the right choice to see the influence of environmental variables on eggs_hatched?

I have tried with multilevel Poisson model, by giving climatic variables as covariates, years and farms as cluster variables, and eggs_hatched as dependent variable. But I am confused about how to include the random effect in the model.

A help would be really appreciated.[image]

Comment: As per [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/632984/69508), it is just a matter of substitution to include random effects into a model.

Comment: @Galen, Could you be more clear please ??

Comment: The post I linked to makes the form of the substitution explicit. I don't how to make it more clear without specific feedback about what is unclear.

Comment: @Galen, I am really sorry. I am a novice in statistical modeling. I have not properly understood 'matter of substitution' / 'substitution explicit' etc.

Comment: Substitution in this context is replacing one expression with another. For example,

$$\theta := t + t$$

means that we assign $\theta$ to be whatever $t+1$ is.

Comment: If you are looking for resources to learn more about statistics, including multilevel models, I recommend [*Statistical Rethinking 2023*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDcUM9US4XdPz-KxHM4XHt7uUVGWWVSus).

Comment: @Galen, Thanks so much for the suggestion. I will definitely watch and learn.